# JSDoc 3 namespace trouble

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

This code

```
/**
 * * My namespace
 *
 * @namespace
 *
 * @type {Object}
 */
myNamespace = {

};

/**
 * My constructor
 *
 * @constructor
 */
myNamespace.MyConstructor = function () {

};

/**
 * My static class function
 *
 */
myNamespace.MyConstructor.myStaticFunction = function () {

};
```

compiles and gives me a nice html file. However the `myConstructor` syntax will show up as `new MyConstrutor()` instead of
the right `new myNamespace.MyConstructor()`.

If I change the comment for `MyConstructor` to

```
/**
 * My constructor
 *
 * @constructor
 * @memberOf {myNamespace}
 */
myNamespace.MyConstructor = function () {

};
```

then I get the expected result of `new myNamespace.MyConstructor()`. However now the `myNamespace.MyConstructor.myStaticFunction` doesn't even show up in
the documentation and no matter what permutation of tags I have tried in any of the 3 comments it will not generate the way I expect it to.

I have tried letting `myStaticFunction` be a member of either `myNamespace` or `MyConstructor` or `myNamespace.MyConstructor` - but it just won't show up in the docs anywhere.

I tried compiling with the old jsdoc-toolkit 2.4 and have no problems and don't even have to use any kind of memberOf notation. It's really late here so I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
* @memberOf myNamespace
```

(no curly brackets)

With JSDoc 3.3.0 *@memberOf {myNamespace}* gives an error.